# Running Windows productivity apps on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualization, wine, application-launch

Can I run Windows apps such as AutoCAD, Rhino, Adobe Photoshop on a Linux machine using some Windows shell?

I saw a [video on LTT](https://youtu.be/IWJUphbYnpg) where Wine was used to run Windows games on Linux, but I wanted to know if I could do just that but with Softwares such as AutoCAD and what kind of performance drop I can expect from that if any?

Also, I'm planning to create a custom Linux skin where when a user logs in to the machine, all they can do is just open those applications and maybe their local drive, just like some Andoird launchers run on windows, like Bluestacks.

Comment: Both AutoCad and Photoshop are heavy duty client apps. If you really need to run these, try Windows 10 Pro as a Virtual Machine via VMware Workstation for Linux.

Comment: Can also run Windows as a guest VM under KVM / QEMU.

Comment: WINE has compatibility list with performance mark, check the software you are going to run - https://appdb.winehq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily - WINE compatibilit with various things is still somewhat problematic. It might work, it might not - you'll have to try it. For professional workloads, your best option is to run a full Windows VM. If I remember correctly, VMware has something called "unity mode" which allows you to run the application in a VM but make it appear as a standalone application rather than being constrained to the VM "screen".

Comment: I think this is the closest we can get right now, so I'll mark it as an answer. 
Thank you